# Android JDK needs to be specified after IDE boots and after new Activities are added

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing in Android Studio 3.0 when earlier today, it hit an IDE Error while I was trying to deploy code and it wasn't able to save my settings. It also said that I should reset the IDE.

After doing so, everything in the code is underlined red. The auto help suggested that I specify the JDK. After setting that, everything was fine and running again. I was able to run and compile my code and test it on a tablet.

However, when I closed and open Android Studio again, the error was back. After the fix mentioned above, I tried adding an activity to the project, and I got this:

[image]

Again, after hitting "Setup JDK" and specifying the JDK (Android API 19 Platform), the project was up and running.

I also noticed this when I opened other projects, I had to specify which JDK to use - and this is getting irritating.

Does anyone know where to setup the JDK for a project so that Android Studio won't ask me every time I open a project or add an activity? I can't find it thus far and Google hasn't been too helpful.